# Enable interactivity in Telerik 3D Charts

Tags: wpf, 3d, telerik

I have a 3D Pyramid chart from Telerik RadControls. I would like to know how we can enable interactivity for this chart (like rotating the pyramid to view it from different angles). The interactivity has been enabled in Telerik Demos, but i wasnt able to understand the code behind. Also, I would like to know whether there is a way we can enable the interactivity through XAML or through some properties of the Chart. Could anyone help me out with this pls? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

For third party controls it is almost always best to ask this sort of question on their forums. They often employ dedicated support engineers who will be happy to answer this sort of question in order to secure more sales!

Telerik have a WPF chart forum here:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/chart.aspx

Comment: yup, i have posted a question there too nw :) thanx!